# Test Observable with fakeAsync, delay and tick using Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, typescript2.0

I have a pipe that helps return the state of an observable.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

/** Specifies the status of an Observable. */
export interface ObservableStatus<T> {
  loading?: boolean;
  value?: T;
  error?: boolean;
}

/** Returns the status {@code ObservableStatus} of a given Observable. */
@Pipe({name: 'getObserverStatus'})
export class ObservableStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T = Item>(observer: Observable<T>):
      Observable<ObservableStatus<T>> {
    return observer.pipe(
        map((value: T) => {
          return {
            loading: false,
            error: false,
            value,
          };
        }),
        startWith({loading: true}),
        catchError(error => of({loading: false, error: true})));
  }
}
```

I want to write unit tests for this functionality using Jasmine. I tried using `fakeAsync, delay, tick, flush, discardPeriodicTasks` but it doesn't seem to work.

##### I have tried different ways:

- Way 1

```
describe('loading test', () => {
  const loadingPipe = new ObservableStatusPipe();

  it('returns state of an observable', fakeAsync(() => {
    const input: Observable<Item> = of({name: 'Item'}).pipe(delay(1000));

    const result: Observable<ObservableStatus<Item>> = loadingPipe.transform(input);

    result.subscribe(val => {
      expect(val.loading).toEqual(true);
      expect(val.value).toBeUndefined();
    });
    tick(2000);
    result.subscribe(val => {
      expect(val.loading).toEqual(false);
      expect(val.value!.name).toEqual('Item');
    });
  }));
});
```

The above test case fails with following failures:

```
Error: Expected true to equal false. (at expect(val.loading).toEqual(false))
Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.
```

- Way 2: From online, I saw that we can use [flush](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flush) to flush any pending tasks.

```
describe('loading test', () => {
  const loadingPipe = new ObservableStatusPipe();

  it('returns state of an observable', fakeAsync(() => {
    const input: Observable<Item> = of({name: 'Item'}).pipe(delay(1000));

    const result: Observable<ObservableStatus<Item>> = loadingPipe.transform(input);

    result.subscribe(val => {
      expect(val.loading).toEqual(true);
      expect(val.value).toBeUndefined();
    });
    tick(2000);
    result.subscribe(val => {
      expect(val.loading).toEqual(false);
      expect(val.value!.name).toEqual('Item');
    });
    flush();     // <----- here.
  }));
});
```

This is helping to resolve `Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.` issue. However the test case still fails with:

```
Error: Expected true to equal false.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

Does all this mean the `tick` is somehow not simulating time on `input` observable?

- I tested the same simulation on `input` observable directly:

```
describe('loading test', () => {
  const loadingPipe = new ObservableStatusPipe();

  it('returns state of an observable', fakeAsync(() => {
    const input: Observable<Item> = of({name: 'Item'}).pipe(delay(1000));

    input.subscribe(val => {
      expect(val.name).toBeUndefined();
    });
    tick(2000);
    input.subscribe(val => {
      expect(val.name).toEqual('Item');
    });
    discardPeriodicTasks();    <--- Using flush() here is causing 'Error: 2 periodic timer(s) still in the queue' error.
  }));
});
```

The above test case is passing. But I am still confused why flush() is not working here.

- Way 3: Tried using the above [discardPeriodicTasks](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/discardPeriodicTasks) trick to solve my original problem.

```
describe('loading test', () => {
  const loadingPipe = new ObservableStatusPipe();

  it('returns state of an observable', fakeAsync(() => {
    const input: Observable<Item> = of({name: 'Item'}).pipe(delay(1000));

    const result: Observable<ObservableStatus<Item>> = loadingPipe.transform(input);

    result.subscribe(val => {
      expect(val.loading).toEqual(true);
      expect(val.value).toBeUndefined();
    });
    tick(2000);
    result.subscribe(val => {
      expect(val.loading).toEqual(false);
      expect(val.value!.name).toEqual('Item');
    });
    discardPeriodicTasks();
  }));
});
```

This still fails with the same errors:

```
Error: Expected true to equal false. (at expect(val.loading).toEqual(false))
Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.
```

Can someone explain what is happening here, and how to solve this, please?

**Btw, I do not want to use `debounceTime`, `setTimeOut` to solve this problem. Because they do not seem to simulate time, instead actually waits and delays time i.e. using debounceTime(1000) will actually wait for 1 sec. I do not want that in my case (I want to simulate time).**

- Using `delay` operator while subscribing the observable is working (without using `tick`).

```
describe('loading test', () => {
  const loadingPipe = new ObservableStatusPipe();

  it('returns state of an observable', fakeAsync(() => {
       const input: Observable<Item> = of({name: 'Item'}).pipe(delay(1000));

       const result: Observable<ObservableStatus<Item>> = loadingPipe.transform(input);

       result.subscribe(val => {
         expect(val.loading).toEqual(true);
         expect(val.value).toBeUndefined();
       });
       result.pipe(delay(2000)).subscribe(val => {
         expect(val.loading).toEqual(false);
         expect(val.value!.name).toEqual('Item');
       });
       discardPeriodicTasks();
     }));
});
```

Is this actually delaying/waiting for 1000 or 2000ms, or does using fakeAsync somehow let delay to simulate the time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your way 1 is good but you may be facing a situation of late subscribers and multiple subscriptions. Try this:

```
    // Take 2 emissions
    result.pipe(take(2)).subscribe(val => {
      if (val.loading) {
        console.log('False case');
        expect(val.loading).toEqual(true);
        expect(val.value).toBeUndefined();
      } else {
        console.log('True case');
        expect(val.loading).toEqual(false);
        expect(val.value!.name).toEqual('Item');
      }
    });
    
    // Move time in a fake way. The above observable stream should hopefully emit 
    // twice and therefore there is a take(2).
    // Make sure you see both console.logs to ensure both paths were asserted.
    tick(2000);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! Using the emission technique on the input observable helped solve my problem.